# How to fix JPanel loop?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have done my simple game of shapes. The codes having 3 JPanel Which is containing Start, Game and end of game. In the code everything is perfect but end of the game i have to include score of game that counts the click of mouse that is score.I cannot include that score.That score page in JPanel which is last panel. and I included the JButtons such as {try again} and {exit}. When I pressed the try again button I cannot see my first Jpanel perfectly  which is contains Start button. How can i fix it ? 
It is heavy code I hope it is not mess

```
    public class myshapestry  implements ActionListener {

        JFrame frame= new JFrame();
        MyPanel panel=new MyPanel();
        Container l ;
        private int ballXSpeed=150;
        private  int ballSpeed=90;
        private  int ballX=150;
        private  int ballY=200;
        Color c=Color.BLACK;
        JLabel statusbar = new JLabel("This game is developed by Asuskobay");
        Startthegame panelstart= new Startthegame();//this is start JPanel
        chooselevel panellevel= new chooselevel();//this is difficulties JPanel
        thegameover gameover=new thegameover();//End of page
       private int mouseclicks;//mouseclicks score
       private int mouse;

         public myshapestry() {

             frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             frame.pack();
             frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
             frame.add(panel);
             frame.add(panellevel);
             frame.add(gameover);
             frame.add(panelstart);
            frame.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.setVisible(true);
             frame.setSize(getPreferredSize());
            frame.setTitle("Game of Shapes");
              HandlerClass handler=new HandlerClass();
                panel.addMouseListener(handler);
                panel.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
                Timer timer=new Timer(100,panel) ;
                timer.start();
            }

         public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
               return new  Dimension(900,730);
           }
         private  class HandlerClass implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
               public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

                 mouseclicks++;
                 statusbar.setText(String.format("MouseLoc ( %d, %d ) \t \t Mouse Click \t", e.getX(), e.getY()) + mouseclicks);
                 mouseclicks=mouse;
               }
              @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                    if(event.getX() <= (ballX+90) && event.getX() >= (ballX)  && event.getY() <= (ballY+90) && event.getY() >= (ballY))
                       c=Color.RED;

                } }
          public  class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

               public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                   super.paintComponent(g);
                   g.setColor(c);
                   g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 90 , 90);
                  }
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //balls movement
                  ballX = ballX + ballXSpeed;
                  ballY = ballY + ballSpeed;
                  if(ballY>=730-185){

                     ballSpeed = -ballSpeed;
                  }

                  if(ballX>=900-180){
                      ballXSpeed = -ballXSpeed;
                  }

                  if(ballY<=0+60){
                      ballSpeed= -ballSpeed;

                  }

                  if (ballX<=0+60){
                      ballXSpeed= -ballXSpeed;
                  }

                  repaint();
                 if(c==Color.RED){
                     frame.remove(panel);
                     frame.add(gameover);
                     frame.validate();
                 }}}
           public class chooselevel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
               private JButton easy;
               private JButton normal;
               private JButton hard;

               public chooselevel(){
                   setLayout(null);
                   easy=new JButton("Easy");
                   normal=new JButton("Normal");
                   hard=new JButton("Hard");

                   easy.setBounds(380,330,90,20);
                   normal.setBounds(380,370,90,20);
                   hard.setBounds(380,410,90,20);
                   add(hard);
                   add(easy);
                   add(normal);
                        hard.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l){
                           String level=l.getActionCommand();
                           if(level.equals("Hard")){
                               ballXSpeed=190;
                               ballSpeed=184;
                               frame.remove(panellevel);
                               frame.add(panel);
                               frame.validate();
                           }} });  

                   normal.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l){
                           String level=l.getActionCommand();
                           if(level.equals("Normal")){
                               ballXSpeed=157;
                               ballSpeed=123;
                               frame.remove(panellevel);
                               frame.add(panel);
                               frame.validate();

                           }}});

                   easy.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l){
                           String level=l.getActionCommand();

                             if(level.equals("Easy")){
                               ballXSpeed=85;
                               ballSpeed=74;
                               frame.remove(panellevel);
                               frame.add(panel);
                               frame.validate();
                              }} });

               } 
              public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                   return new Dimension(900,730);
               } }
           public class Startthegame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
               private JButton Start;
                private JButton Exit;

                public Startthegame() {
                    setLayout(null);

                    Start = new JButton("Start");
                    Exit = new JButton("Exit");

                    Start.setBounds(380,330,70,20);
                    Exit.setBounds(380,370,70,20);
                    add(Start);
                    add(Exit);
                     Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                     public  void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent i){
                       String action= i.getActionCommand();
                       if(action.equals("Exit")) {
                         System.exit(0);
                       }}
                 });
                    Start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                         public  void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent i){
                           String action= i.getActionCommand();
                           if(action.equals("Start")) {
                               frame.remove(panelstart);
                               frame.add(panellevel);
                               frame.validate();
                               repaint();
                           } }});
}
    @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(900, 730);
                } }
           public class thegameover extends JPanel {
               private JLabel gameisover;
               private JLabel yourscore;
               private JButton tryagain;
               private JButton Exit;
               thegameover(){
                   setLayout(null);

                   gameisover= new JLabel("GAME OVER");
                   yourscore=new JLabel();

                  add(gameisover);
                  add(yourscore);
                   gameisover.setBounds(170,200,600,70);
                   yourscore.setBounds(380,380,120,70);

                  gameisover.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 90));
                  yourscore.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 20));
                  yourscore.setText ("Your Score " + mouseclicks);

                  tryagain=new JButton("Try Again");
                  Exit=new JButton("Exit");
                  add(tryagain);
                  add(Exit);

                  tryagain.setBounds(280,550,100,20);
                  Exit.setBounds(490,550,100,20);

                  tryagain.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ac){
                          String tryit=ac.getActionCommand();
                                if(tryit.equals("Try Again")){
                                     frame.remove(gameover);
                                       frame.add(panelstart);
                                       frame.validate();
                                       repaint();
                                }
                            }
                  });
               }
               public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                   return new Dimension(900,73);
               }}
            public static void main (String args[]){
               EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {

                       myshapestry tr=new myshapestry();
                   }
               });
             }  }
```

AFTER EDIT:

I have created new Jpanel to collect all Jpanels inside of this to add statusbar in Frame but I got errors something is going wrong

```
public class myshapestry  implements ActionListener {
    collectionpanel collectpanel= new collectionpanel();

public myshapestry() {
        frame.add(collectpanel);
public class collectionpanel extends JPanel {



         collectionpanel(){
                cardlayout= new CardLayout();
                 this.setLayout(cardlayout);
                 this.add(panel, "game");
                this.add(panellevel,"level");
                 this.add(gameover, "over");
                 this.add(panelstart, "start");

                 cardlayout.show(collectpanel, "game");
             cardlayout.show(collectpanel, "level");
             cardlayout.show(collectpanel, "start");
             cardlayout.show(collectpanel, "over");     

         } }
```

The errors;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
    at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.CardLayout.show(Unknown Source)
    at example.myshapestry$collectionpanel.<init>(myshapestry.java:100)
    at example.myshapestry.<init>(myshapestry.java:58)
    at example.myshapestry$1.run(myshapestry.java:393)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: ...hmmm.  377 lines of code.  Well, 377 lines of some code and lots of white space.  Not quite 'minimal' in my view.  Please remove the unnecessary blank lines (not the code indent), and make particular effort to remove any code that does not help us see the problem.

Comment: I removed the white lines but I didnt remove any code because these codes have communication between

Comment: `setLayout(null);` isn't going to help; `frame.setSize(getPreferredSize());` -> `frame.pack()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a cascade of problems, all of which act together to cause chaos...

1. When the game is "over", you never stop the `Timer`, this means that when you try and show the "game over" screen or try to restart, the "game panel" is still trying to update the screen...
2. This is compounded by the management of you screens.  You add all the screens to start with, but then remove/add them again later, which is just causing a mess.

Instead...

1. Before you make the "game screen" visible, start the `Timer`.  When you detect that the game is "over", before you show the "over" screen, stop the `Timer`
2. Use a `CardLayout` instead.  See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

For example...

Create a `CardLayout` instance field and make the `Timer` an instance field as well

```
public class MyShapes {//implements ActionListener {
    //...       
    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(100, panel);
```

Apply the `CardLayout` to the `frame` and name each view...

```
public MyShapes() {
    //...       
    cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    frame.setLayout(cardLayout);

    frame.add(panel, "game");
    frame.add(panellevel, "level");
    frame.add(gameover, "over");
    frame.add(panelstart, "start");
    frame.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    cardLayout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "start");
    //...
}
```

When the user selects to "start", switch the view using the `CardLayout`

```
Start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent i) {
        String action = i.getActionCommand();
        if (action.equals("Start")) {
            //frame.remove(panelstart);
            //frame.add(panellevel);
            //frame.validate();
            cardLayout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "level");
        }
    }
});
```

When you start a game, start the `Timer` and use the `CardLayout` to switch the view...

```
hard.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l) {
        String level = l.getActionCommand();
        if (level.equals("Hard")) {
            ballXSpeed = 190;
            ballSpeed = 184;
            //frame.remove(panellevel);
            //frame.add(panel);
            //frame.validate();
            timer.start();
            cardLayout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "game");
        }
    }
});
```

When you detect a "game over" condition, stop the `Timer` and use the `CardLayout` to switch the view...

```
if (c == Color.RED) {
    //frame.remove(panel);
    //frame.add(gameover);
    //frame.validate();
    timer.stop();
    cardLayout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "over");
}
```

Now, to the scoring issue...

When you create the `thegameover` panel, you use `yourscore.setText("Your Score " + mouseclicks);`, but `mouseclicks` is `0` when you create the view, you need someway to update this value....

Add a method to the `thegameover` the class, called something like `setScore` and update the label accordingly...

```
public void setScore(int score) {
    yourscore.setText("Your Score " + score);
}
```

When you detect a game over condition, update the score...

```
timer.stop();
gameover.setScore(mouseclicks);
cardLayout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "over");
```

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

It would also be worth while having a read of [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Thank you so much MadProgrammer. I have done ıt is now perfect. But I cannot include the statusbar(JLabel)

Comment: Oh, I see place your changing views into a separate JPanel, using a CardLayout, add this and the status label to the frame using a BorderLayout. You'll have to change all the cardLayout.show calls to use this new panel instead of the frame

Comment: So what should ı do ? If I change the cardLayout I will face same problem

Comment: No, you don't. Instead of using the frame as the primary container, create a JPanel, applying a CardLayout to it and adding all your "views" to it. You can then add the status panel and the "card panel" to the frame

Comment: As I said, instead of using `cardLayout.show(frame, ...)`, you'll need to use `cardLayout.show(whatEverPanelYoureNowUsing, ...)`.  Also, make sure you have a read through [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Only call `CardLayout#show` for the component you want to become visible, all the other components will remain hidden

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer it is done.I have removed the JPanel (card panel) class, instead of JPanel classs , I create directly JPanel in the main class. And In the myshapestry constructor, i included all of panel by "card panel".